# Error:interface must be a pointer to struct Error Returned in fiber (golang), how to solve this?

Tags: go, struct, interface, fibers, go-fiber

I'm new in Golang Programming
I'm Faceing an issue..
I'm trying to acces my sent body data by "BodyParser"functtion
But I got an error

> schema: interface must be a pointer to struct

I'm Giving the Function Bellow

```
func CreateService(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    if c.Locals("user_type") != "1" {
        return c.SendString("Wrong One")

    }

    file, err := c.FormFile("image")

    // Check for errors:
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return c.JSON("Something error")
    }
    //  Save file to root directory:
    c.SaveFile(file, fmt.Sprintf("./%s", file.Filename))
    //  Save file inside uploads folder under current working directory:
    c.SaveFile(file, fmt.Sprintf("./uploads/%s", file.Filename))
    //  Save file using a relative path:
    c.SaveFile(file, fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/uploads_relative/%s", file.Filename))

    var data map[string]string

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    service := models.Services{
        Title: data["title"],
        Src:   PORT + "/" + file.Filename,
    }
    database.DB.Create(&service)

    return c.JSON(service)
}
```

model.Services is

```
type Services struct {
    Id    uint   `json:"id"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Src   string `json:"src"`
}
```

Please Help me out. Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Which line of code generates the error?

Comment: [`BodyParser`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2#Ctx.BodyParser) documentation says: *"BodyParser binds the request body to a struct."* but you are passing `&data` which is of type `*map[string]string` and that's a pointer-to-`map` not a pointer-to-`struct`. Does the error `interface must be a pointer to struct` make more sense now?

Answer (score 2):

We need to provide pointer to a struct in GoFiber_v2 not *map[string]string. This is causing the issue.

Below Function for getting data from GoFiber_v2 BodyParser:

```
func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var user models.User

    err := c.BodyParser(&user)
    if err != nil {
    return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#+v", user)
}
```

Model Package

```
package models

type User struct {
    Id        uint   `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
    Password  string `json:"password"`
}
```